# Joining a table to itself to compare two different types of fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

sorry for the confusing title.

I have two tables, `individu` and `orgcont`. `individu` looks something like:

```
individu
-------------
ind_id
org_id
email
```

`orgcont` looks something like:

```
orgcont
-------------
ind_id
function_code
```

I have many users that can belong to the same `org_id` and they each of their own `ind_id`. The 'leaders' of the org_id have a function code of 'PRIM', everyone else's are irrelevant. I am trying to return a list of `org_id` and `email` of all of the users who have a 'PRIM' `function code` who have users that have NULL email addresses that are not 'PRIM'.

I have something like this, but the results are not correct. Any help would be appreciated:

```
select
    i.email,
    i.org_id
from
    individu i,
    orgcont o,
    individu i2,
    orgcont o2
where
    i.ind_id = o.ind_id
    and i.org_id = i2.org_id
    and i2.ind_id = o2.ind_id
    and o.function_code = 'PRIM'
    and o2.function_code != 'PRIM'
    and i2.email is NULL
```

Comment: "... the results are not correct" how?

Comment: Your joins do not seem to be correct. Note that the syntax you're using for joining is outdated. It's better and clearer to use the explicit JOIN syntax: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: @AbeMiessler - OP's probably getting duplicate rows, as there's no `distinct` on the column set. Ergo, I did it with `exists`. Even if s/he is a Pens fan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with `exists`:

```
select
    i.email,
    i.org_id
from
    individu i
    inner join orgcont o on
        i.ind_id = o.ind_id
where
    o.function_code = 'PRIM'
    and exists (
        select
            1
        from
            individu i2
            inner join orgcont o2 on
                i2.ind_id = o2.ind_id
        where
            i2.org_id = i.org_id
            and o2.function_code != 'PRIM'
            and i2.email is null
    )
```

This will only return you one row for each leader with folks in their org with `null` email addresses, as opposed to your original query, which will return duplicate rows.

Also note the join syntax--you want to do an `inner join` here, not a `cross join`, so do so explicitly.

Additionally, you could have just done a `select distinct`, but that's a little more expensive than the `exists`.

Comment: Thanks for the notes Eric, whodathunk such talent would come from (presumably) a Stars fan! ;-)

Comment: @etm124 - Bruins fan, actually :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, the **INNER JOIN** to the sub query will act as the filter

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.email, i.org_id
FROM individu i 
     INNER JOIN orgcont o ON i.ind_id = o.ind_id
     INNER JOIN 
     (  SELECT i.id
        FROM individu i 
             INNER JOIN orgcont o ON i.ind_id = o.ind_id
        WHERE o.function_code != 'PRIM' AND i.email IS NULL 
     ) t ON t.id = i.id
WHERE o.function_code = 'PRIM'
```

Comment: No reason to do a subquery here--just adds a little complexity and also execution time. Joining both those table would work just fine, so long as you have the `distinct`.